# What is diffrent between these syntax please Explain in details?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

What is diffrent between these syntax please Explain in details?

```
$(document).on("click", "#index1", function() {
    $(p).hide();
});
$("#index2").on("click", "#index1", function() {
    $(p).hide();
});
$("#index1").on("click", function() {
    $(p).hide();
});
```

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: ^ it's all explained there, in great detail.

Comment: Stack isn't a school or a tutorial site. It's somewhere that you come to in order to ask help with trouble with code you're having with and this what looks to me as valid syntax for code. Plus, since you didn't make a mention of that IMHO doesn't qualify as a question, then it's up to you to read and learn from the manuals, try something and if something doesn't work, then come back and post a (real) question.

Comment: Plus, there is no php as per tagged, (edit) that I have removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case you add click listener to "document", but it be executed only if you click at "#index1". 
In second - you add listener to "index2" and it will be executed only if you click at "#index1" located inside of "#index2". 
In the third case you just add listener to "index1"

Comment: thankyou... by the way i was confused in second. now clear

Answer (score 0):

Lets imagine a webpage at first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id='index1'>click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

1. This will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id='index1'>click me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#index1").on("click", function () {
            $(p).hide();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

2. This won't work, because the element did not exist while the script was executed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#index1").on("click", function () {
            $(p).hide();
        });
    </script>
    <button id='index1'>click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

But with a workaround, it would

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("click", "#index1", function() {
            $(p).hide();
        });
    </script>
    <button id='index1'>click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This says whenever a click event is fired on the document check if the click was fired on `#index1` element. So even if, the element did not exist the callback, is attached to the document node. Now whenever a click is fired on the document it will check if it originated from `#index1`